# Vim Ctrl-Left/Ctrl-Right keys behaviour

Tags: vim

Is it possible to specify the symbols where cursor will stop after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> keys in VIM? Is it possible to make it's behaviour like in windows? Cursor jumps too far when using these combinations. Also, <kbd>b</kbd>/<kbd>e</kbd> keys help a bit but they make cursor to jump to shorter distance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the vim help `:help word`

> ```
>                               *word*
> ```
>
> A word consists of a sequence
>   of letters, digits and underscores, or
>   a sequence of other non-blank
>   characters, separated with white space
>   (spaces, tabs, ).  This can be
>   changed with the 'iskeyword' option. 
>   An empty line is also considered to be
>   a word.

Comment: The default setting is the next  
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255

Comment: Thanks!
It didn't helped me a lot, but thanks to your answer I came across the difference between inclusive and exclusive motions. All I needed is to use exclusive motions:
Shift-Right/Shift-Left or w/W

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend to use the vim-typical commands like w/W/b/B/e/E/ge/gE/f/F/t/T instead of the arrow keys. The arrow keys are far away from your keyboard home row and will slow you down.

More help on important movement commands:

```
:h word-motions
:h object-motions
:h left-right-motions
```

Comment: Sure, but as for me it's more convenient to find Shift or Ctrl key without watching on the keyboard than to find w/Shift-w.
p.s. No holy wars. Just my own impressions. :)

Comment: Hi kongo2002,
I want to use ctrl+arrow keys becouse it can work in insert mode too...

my problem is, that if I map C-Right to sequence esc-e-i (or whatever) it always insert weird delay between interpreting map...

I press Ctrl+RightArrow, vim waits about 2 seconds and then finally jump one word to the right. Why is that? 
(I'm using Ubuntu... if this matter)

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: @andrej often you have to play with the settings `timeout` `ttimeout` `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen` to get those mapping timeouts right